# E-mail links do nothing when I click on them

Tags: yahoo-mail

Some links in my yahoo email will not open or do anything when clicking or long pressing on them .
Ones that work are in emails that I have clicked on always show pictures .
The emails that did not pop up that window I cannot get links to open. 
They all worked fine on my Maxx but my new Moto z is where I'm having these problems.

Comment: Not a bad first question. Try removing and reinstalling the app/app updates.